# why my Mac stop working when I use merge function

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am trying to use merge function for these two data set but my Mac stop working when I use this code:

```
       WithBus<-merge(bus,ID, all.y = TRUE)
```

here str for both

```
str(bus)
'data.frame':   2456 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ SAMPN.1    : Factor w/ 3847 levels "    2","    5",..: 3 3 5 10 15 19 22 28 29 33 ...
 $ PERNO.1    : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ PLANO.1    : Factor w/ 21 levels " 2"," 3"," 4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 ...
 $ loop.1     : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 ...
 $ MODE1.1    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 2 2 4 4 2 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ walk.1     : Factor w/ 14960 levels "-0.000235854687434333",..: 11898 11203 1019 9365 8897 9602 13905 2151 9022 10979 ...
 $ car.1      : Factor w/ 15009 levels " 2909"," 2976",..: 4835 5378 12560 13625 955 9463 2999 13452 10634 3638 ...
 $ bus.1      : Factor w/ 14960 levels "-0.00234902134438422",..: 13632 13733 13564 13419 14135 13883 13381 13719 13652 13549 ...
 $ utipassen.1: Factor w/ 14960 levels "-0.000221832418741408",..: 241 11291 9145 10402 6150 12653 9866 12688 11484 4026 ...
 $ bus.walk   : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ mode.bus   :'data.frame':    2456 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ V1: num  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...


> str(ID)
'data.frame':   24812 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ SAMPN    : Factor w/ 3853 levels "    2","    5",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ MODE1    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ PERNO    : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ PLANO    : Factor w/ 24 levels " 2"," 3"," 4",..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ loop     : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ ARR_HR   : Factor w/ 24 levels " 1"," 2"," 3",..: 8 9 10 17 8 13 13 16 17 17 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ ARR_MIN  : Factor w/ 60 levels " 0"," 1"," 2",..: 26 49 21 51 6 11 26 31 11 21 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ start_hr : Factor w/ 24 levels " 1"," 2"," 3",..: 8 9 10 17 7 13 13 16 16 17 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ start_min: Factor w/ 60 levels " 0"," 1"," 2",..: 21 31 6 11 41 6 21 6 51 16 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ VEHLIC   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ licence2 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ TPURP    : Factor w/ 22 levels "(1) Working at home (for pay)",..: 10 4 16 12 16 9 16 5 5 5 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ walk     : Factor w/ 21527 levels "-0.000134409654909421",..: 13885 1223 14878 4464 9652 10224 6089 2794 3502 17 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ car      : Factor w/ 21527 levels "-0.000667367461145929",..: 9204 14366 11706 18959 19625 9781 9745 16400 16530 8704 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ bus      : Factor w/ 21527 levels "-0.00234902134438422",..: 9126 8248 18610 8619 8289 16137 7522 7426 9999 9001 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
 $ utipassen: Factor w/ 21527 levels "-0.000203965202547889",..: 8269 7469 7905 7637 19815 20050 20391 720 5877 4429 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4" "5" "6" ...
```

I had larger data set and I've never had this kind of problem. the memory and cpu of my Mac is good enough and I know problem is something else . could you plz check it out?

Comment: Try using `left_join` from `dplyr` or a join with `data.table`.  are you joining by all the common columns?  If not, subset the data and specify the `by`

Comment: bus is a subset of ID and it has a new column . I want whole ID with this new column. if a row in ID was not in bus then NA for that new column

Comment: There are some issues I noted in your dataset.  please do the correction. for that. and try `merge` again

Comment: what is `intersect(names(bus), names(ID))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be couple of issues.

1) The column names are not exactly same in both datasets (`SAMPN.1` vs `SAMPN`)

2) The `by` or (`by.x`, `by.y` - if the column names are different) are not specified

3) `merge` would be slower.  Use either `left_join` from `dplyr` or join from `data.table`

4) If only a subset of columns are required in the second dataset, select those columns

5) There are additional `attr`ibutes in the 'ID' dataset which can be removed

6) One of the column `mode.bus` is a `data.frame` column

`:'data.frame':    2456 obs. of  1 variable:`

Change that column to a normal column as well

```
bus <- do.call(data.frame, bus)
```

With `by` arugment, the `merge` can be

```
 merge(bus,ID, all.y = TRUE, by.x = 'SAMPN.1', by.y = 'SAMPN')
```

If we need only `select` columns from 'bus', use only those

Comment: also do you know why I have some duplicate row when I use merge function? rows with exactly the same value in all columns.

Comment: @hghg It could be because you have duplicate rows for the ``by` column value in both dataset.  If you reemove the duplicate for that in the `bus`, it would work fine